# Route change after navigate one time in asp net core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I try to navigate to page in my asp net core project it's work fine, then when I try to navigate second time the route change to unusable route like it been converted to ascii character, the '/' be %2F,
so the route failed to navigate me correctly.

**sample :** 
**first route : `/Identity/Account/Manage/Community/Opinion` 

the second time route :`?page=%2FAccount%2FManage%2FCommunity%2FCommunity%2FOpinion`**

**any idea why this happen.** 
Thank you all.

the code is below :
**Opinion.cshtml.cs :**

```
public class OpinionModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private HcmTextContentRepository repo;

    public OpinionModel(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        repo = new HcmTextContentRepository(new HCMContext());
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Contant { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Opinion Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Opinion Content")]
        public string Contant { get; set; }
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        var result = new HcmTextContent();
        result.TextTitle = Input.Title;
        result.TextContent = Input.Contant;
        result.HowsAddedTextId = userId;
        result.TextAddDate = DateTime.Now;
        result.TextLastModifidDate = DateTime.Now;
        var final = repo.addTextContent(result);

        StatusMessage = "Your Opinion is Added.";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
}
```

---

**Opinion.cshtml :**

```
@page
@model HCMProject.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Community.OpinionModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage Email";
    ViewData["ActivePage"] = ManageNavPages.Opinion;
 }
 <partial name="_StatusMessage" model="Model.StatusMessage" />
 <form id="opinion-form" method="post">
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="container addopinio">
    <h3 class="text-dark mb-1">Add New Opinion</h3>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <label asp-for="Input.Title"></label>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input asp-for="Input.Title" id="Opinion_title_id" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <label asp-for="Input.Contant"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="=row">
            <textarea id="summernote" asp-for="Input.Contant"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.Contant" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <button id="add-opnion-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Your Opinion</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: When you will get the second route?After submitting the form?

Comment: @Yiyi, yes after submit form